# Find a point in rage of entries : Mongo db

Tags: mongodb

Here is my Secnario :

1 to 10 - Mapped to A

11 to 14 - Mapped to B

15 to 16 - Mapped to C

16 to 50 - Mapped to D

I need to know where does the input (Say 5 for example) ?
5 lies with the range of 1 to 10, hence it should be mapped to A.

Need to design this in Monogo ? How should I have the data and how we we should query ?

Answer (score 0):

I see two options here: one is a series of nested [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/)s, another is the [`$bucket`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/bucket/) operator.

Using `$cond` is fairly simple:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$project: {
        category: {$cond: {
            if: {$lte: ['$field', 10]},
            then: 'A',
            else: {$cond: {
                if: {$lte: ['$field', 14]},
                then: 'B',
                else: ...
            }}
        }}
    }}
])
```

And so on. I hope you got the idea.

Using `$bucket` is not any hard, but definitely harder to grasp:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$bucket: {
        groupBy: '$field',
        // These are exclusive on the upper bound!
        boundaries: [1, 10.1, 14.1, 16.1, 50.1],
        default: 'Other',
        output: {
            docs: {$push: '$$ROOT'}
        }
    }}
])
```

These two output completely different shapes, so you'll have to play with it and adjust as needed.